VS2022: Watch contents of managed variable in the watch when only knowing its actual address
I've got a (legally) decompiled C# code. Variables shown in that code cannot be queried from the watch (Visual Studio). Debugging dually with the disassembly pane, I came across the address of the object I'd like to inspect in a register.
Let's assume a fictitious example address: 0x0000007f12345678, and we know that an object of fictitious type name.space.MyClass sits there.
I attempted to do some things like these below, that yielded errors every time:

*(name.space.MyClass*)0x0000007f12345678 (yields error "This debugger is unable to evaluate this expression")
(name.space.MyClass*)0x0000007f12345678 (yields error "Unable to read memory" on unfolded pointed data, whereas that memory can be shown in a memory pane with actual present+user_readable pages, no '??' I mean)

Is it a consequence of type lookup not working properly with source files resulting from decompiling? Is using pointers of the unsafe realm N/A here? Is there a way to circumvent?
Thanks.

Addresses are meaningless in a garbage-collected language.  They'll change randomly, out of sync with program execution.  So the debugger intentionally does nothing to help you with this, very misleading in the Watch window for example.  All you got is Debug > Windows > Memory.

Yeah, indeed, I know that very well on a commercial point of view. Not an excuse though objectively on the vendor part. Still, if someone comes up with an idea, I'm still a taker. An answer to this could be in the decompiler department, whose variable watching could be improved... Indeed, resorting to disassembling and peeking in regs was just a workaround, knowing this is jitted C#.

You could try searching for decompilcation and debugging tools in VS extension marketplace.
